# Pictures taken with the camera come out really dark on iOS w/ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturesession

The camera preview looks perfect, but when I take a picture and save it to the Camera Roll the picture comes out extremely dark. Tried a bunch of threads on here but nothing solved it. Here's my code.

This sets up the camera/preview and works fine:

```
 captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

        // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
        for device in devices {
            // Make sure this particular device supports video
            if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
                if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                    captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                }
            }
        }

        if captureDevice != nil {
            beginSession()
        }

func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil

    if captureSession.canAddInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err)) {
        captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

        if err != nil {
            println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(cameraButton)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame

        // start camera
        captureSession.startRunning()

   }
```

This is called when the picture is taken:

```
@IBAction func photoTaken(sender: UIButton) {

    stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    }
    var videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if videoConnection != nil {

        // Show next step button
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.nextStep)
        self.nextStep.hidden = false

        // Secure image
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)

                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

        }

        // Freeze camera preview
        captureSession.stopRunning()


    }

}
```

This is called after the picture is taken when the user hits the button to proceed (it saves the image to the camera roll for now, but will eventually do more when I get the images to look good):

```
@IBAction func nextStepTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    // Save to camera roll & proceeed
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil)

}
```

My guess is that the issue is within the photoTaken() function, but I have no idea. This is my first time writing an app in Swift/Xcode, so any help would greatly be appreciated. Again, the issue is that the saved photo is extremely dark and I've tried pretty much everything I could find on the internet related to this problem, but nothing works. Thanks!

Edit: Might be worth noting that I'm testing this on an iPhone 4S. Could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue was that I was calling this as the photo was being taken:

```
 stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
     if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
         captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
     }
```

I moved that section from photoTaken() (called when a picture is taken) to beginSession() (called to initiate the camera) and now it works. Setting up the output after the photo button was pressed probably caused a lag/delay and didn't enable the camera to fully go through the motions.

Comment: Do you know if there's another solution? Imagine I'm building a camera app that takes a photo as soon as it's launched, without the user having to press the shutter button. How do I add the output to the session and take a photo as soon as possible without it being dark? BTW, I'm using the new photo output, not the old still image output.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a callback/delegate/notification for when the camera is fully ready?

Answer (score 0):

"First time the app is executed, the first call to AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice() triggers a system dialog, asking the user to allow usage of the camera. This was introduced in some countries with iOS 7, and was extended to all regions with iOS 8. Until the user accepts the dialog, the camera input will send a stream of black frames."

You can find more here: http://www.objc.io/issue-21/camera-capture-on-ios.html

Comment: I accepted the camera dialog. The picture isn't a black frame, it's just extremely dim. The preview looks fine then when I hit take picture it darkens significantly and freezes the preview on the dark image. I'll read that link...

Comment: That link is actually the tutorial I've been using. Tried the exposure/white balance stuff and that didn't help.